Effects Contrast Matrix for Interaction with Multiple Grand Means
I want to include an interaction between two factors: area and house_type, in my GAM (MGCV), I hope to make a sum-to-zero contrast encoding.
But, I do not want each combination of the factors to be compared to the grand mean across all levels. I want a grand mean for each level of area. So then the house_types within each area are compared to the grand mean for that area.
Here's what I've tried
Taking the contrast matrix for house_type. There are 7 types: it is a 7*6 matrix.

For 6 levels of area I created a matrix made up of the house_type contrast matrices on the diagonal and null matrices of the same size on the off diagonals. This is 42*36.
The first two submatrices are shown here:

Queries

Is there a better way to do this?
Running a simple linear regression with the interaction term, I get NA coefficients - why is this?
Is there an overall intercept in this model or is it one intercept for each level of area representing the grand mean?

Thank you
